# Nth child list displaying wrongly

Tags: css

i have this code

```
<ul id="task-ul">
        <li><a>Personal</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Meetings</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Email/call</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Follow up</a></li>
    </ul>
```

CSS

```
#task-ul li a:nth-child(1){
     border-bottom: 2px  solid blue;
    }
    #task-ul li a:nth-child(2){
     border-bottom: 2px  solid aqua;
    }
    #task-ul li a:nth-child(3){
     border-bottom: 2px  solid yellow;
    }
```

but they all color blue what could be the problem
[image]

Comment: You are selecting every first `a` child in every `li` element.

Comment: yes thats what i wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to target the different list-items in the selectors, not the links

```
#task-ul li:nth-child(1) a { 
 border-bottom: 2px  solid blue;
}
#task-ul li:nth-child(2) a {
 border-bottom: 2px  solid aqua;
}
#task-ul li:nth-child(3) a {
 border-bottom: 2px  solid yellow;
}
```

Actually your CSS is trying to match this markup structure

```
<ul id="task-ul">
    <li>
        <a>Personal</a>
        <a href="">Meetings</a>
        <a href="">Email/call</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

That's why your selectors cannot work as you expect (except the first one)

Comment: i targeted the links because when i put on the list the border bottom becomes too long

Comment: your selectors actually don't match nothing (except the first one)

Comment: what do do you mean by dont match nothing

Comment: @girliosalama please read my update. Also a CSS reference can be useful : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child